# read-char-from-minibuffer for optional argument

Tags: characters, read

The  following counts the number of opening (`brcmk-beg`) and closing (`brcmk-end`) braces.  Having `brcmk-end` an optional argument, I would like to print

`$begmk nil $count-begmk 0`

when the user either hits `Return` or uses a blank space when using the minibeffer with the call `(read-char-from-minibuffer "Closing Bracemark: ")`.

```lisp
    (cl-defun rk-bracemark-count-from-char
        (brcmk-beg &optional brcmk-end
                             (rgn-beg (region-beginning))
                             (rgn-end (region-end)))
      "Count number of opening and closing brace marks.
    Search is applied within a region."
    
      (interactive
       (list (read-char-from-minibuffer "Opening Bracemark: ")
             (read-char-from-minibuffer "Closing Bracemark: ")
             (region-beginning)
             (region-end) ))
    
      (save-excursion
        (let ( ($count-begmk  0) ($count-endmk  0) 
               ($begmk  (char-to-string brcmk-beg))
               ($endmk  (or (and brcmk-end (char-to-string brcmk-end))
                "nil")) )
    
          (goto-char rgn-beg)
          (while (and (< (point) rgn-end)
                      (search-forward $begmk rgn-end t))
            (cl-incf $count-begmk))
    
          (goto-char rgn-beg)
          (while (and brcmk-end
                  (< (point) rgn-end)
                  (search-forward $endmk rgn-end t))
            (cl-incf $count-endmk))
    
          (message "Marks: %s %s  Counts: %d %d" $begmk $endmk
               $count-begmk $count-endmk)
          (goto-char rgn-beg) )))
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. `read-char-from-minibuffer` cannot return *"empty"* or return more than one char (*"composed of spaces"*). Please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Why don't you write you own read function (based on `read-char-from-minibuffer`) that return `nil` when you don't get the input you want. I *guess* that would make the function use the default argument. (Personally, I haven't used `cl-defun` so I'm not familiar with default arguments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(require 's) ; for s-blank-str-p

...
  (interactive
    (list (read-char-from-minibuffer "Opening Bracemark: ")
          (let ((x (read-char-from-minibuffer "Closing Bracemark: ")))
            (unless (s-blank-str-p (char-to-string x)) x))
          (region-beginning)
          (region-end)))
  ;; at this point brcmk-end is either nil or a closing delimiter
...
```

Comment: So when user hits `Return`, the local variable `x` is `nil`. Otherwise `x` gets converted to a string.  Right?

Comment: Would I need to install the feature `s`?

Comment: I figure that the line `(unless (s-blank-str-p (char-to-string x)) x)` should be `(unless (s-blank-str-p (char-to-string x)) x))`

Comment: Yes, package `s` is in the MELPA repository (and probably others). It's a comprehensive library of string-oriented functions.

Comment: You're quite right about the parens, fixed now.